# Tentando Abrir rapidamente uma Tabela enorme com FDTable

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Olá, o problema que estou enfrentando é: Tenho uma tabela com 120.353 registros preciso fazer uma correção geral na tabela e quanto tento `FDTable.Active := True` fica em processo interminavelmente... estou usando FireBird 2.5...
O que Faze?

index da tabela

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_AND_PRO_AUX ON ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS(NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX);

CREATE INDEX IDX_PUBLICACAO ON ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS(CODIGO_PUBLICACAO);
```

Teria alguma maneira de abrir a tabela sem carregar todos os registros?

Comment: o que queres dizer com 'preciso fazer uma correção geral'? É um _edit_ a um/varios registos existentes? Um _insert_?

Comment: É por que abri a tabela pelo sistema está lento e eu preciso corrigir isso e questão do geral é por que sabendo como repara vou ver se é aplicável as outras tabelas no `dataModule`.

Comment: Mas na tua app queres apenas abrir a tabela para mostrar uma grid aos utilizadores, ou queres navegar pelos registos para fazer alteraçoes aos dados pelo FDTable (FDTable.Edit, alteraçoes, FDTable.Post)?

Comment: não uso queres... é a própria tabela...
isso acontece quando eu abro o sistema e no inicio eu tenho que abrir 3 tabelas... 
`DataModuleGeral.tbAndamentosConsulta.Open;
 DataModuleGeral.tbPublicacoesConsulta.Open;
 DataModuleGeral.tbAudienciasConsulta.Open;`

Comment: não uso queres... é a própria tabela...
isso acontece quando eu abro o sistema e no inicio eu tenho que abrir 3 tabelas... 
`DataModuleGeral.tbAndamentosConsulta.Open;
 DataModuleGeral.tbPublicacoesConsulta.Open;
 DataModuleGeral.tbAudienciasConsulta.Open;`,isso faz demorar muito Cerca de 50 segundos a 2 minutos para abrir...

Comment: Podes usar FDQuery's para fazerem praticamente o mesmo que as FDTable. A unica diferença é que em vez de dizeres apenas o nome da tabela, tinhas de por a Query SQL lá na FDquery. Mas acaba por ser mais fléxivel...

Comment: Como está a propriedade Mode?
*FdTable.FetchOptions.Mode*

Comment: `Table.FetchOptions.Mode := fmOnDemand`

Comment: @EduardoMendonçadaSilva se consegui ajudar com a minha resposta, pode aceitar a resposta clicando no ✔ no lado esquerdo da mesma. Se necessitar de alguma mais ajuda avise.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu objectivo é apenas limitar o numero de registos a abrir por exemplo a 5.000 apenas precisa de usar o seguinte código:

```
SELECT FIRST 5000 * FROM tabela ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Ao contrário do *MySQL* que podemos usar o `Limit` no *FireBird* aqui usa-se o `First`.

[FireBirdSQL](http://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-first-skip)

Comment: Mais é uma `FDTable` enão uma `FDQuary` tem como fazer isso na `FDTable` ?

Comment: @EduardoMendonçadaSilva eu não tenho forma de testar porque não tenho o delphi instalado, mas deve haver forma de associar o FDQuery ao FDTable

Comment: no sistema que trabalho tenho que abrir uma 3 tabelas. Essas Tabelas são as mais utilizadas pelos usuários por isso não as maiores... eu creio que o problema seja que alguns campos dessa tabela que tem o tamanho de 8000 caracteres. como não sistema não é meu é da empresa onde trabalho eu fico as vezes sem ter o que fazer...

Answer (score 0):

Caso tenhas grids associadas com estas `FDTable`, fazer o `disableControls()` para 'cortar' a ligaçao tabela-grids antes de a abrir costuma acelerar bastante.

Algo como:

```
FDTable.DisableControls;
FDTable.Open;
FDTable.EnableControls;
```

Para fazeres como já aqui te sugeriram, limitar o numero de registos trazidos de cada vez numa `FDTable` tens de escolher essas opções nas *FetchOptions* da `FDTable`.
Há uma serie de parametros que podes usar para acelerar a leitura da tabela, mas neste caso diria que precisas de editar o *Mode* para *fmExactRecsMax* e editares o valor de  *RecsMax*

Mas o melhor é ver a documentação em
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Fetching_Rows_(FireDAC)

Comment: Eu abro as tabelas no inicio do sistema logo não tenho grids. Eu estou tentando configura essa questão do `FetchOption` mais sempre levanta uma exceção:
([FireDAC][Phys][FB]-312. Exact fetch returned [1501] rows, while [1500] was requested.)